# Validate/Restrict app containers to specific base image(s)

Tags: azure, docker, containers, ado, azure-container-registry

We have a private Azure Container Registry and I am looking for a way to restrict the use of any public base images. Before an application image is built and pushed to ACR there should be a validation not to use mcr.microsoft.com, but to use acr.xxxxx.com.
The idea is to make sure base images that are used to containerize applications, should be from a private registry.

Comment: why disallow public base images ? if you wanna build dotnet app you should relay on 
MS based images, if you wanna use nginx you probably wanna use nginx maintained imaged etc ....

Comment: maybe acr tasks can help but not sure: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-tasks-overview

Comment: Thanks @Thomas I will check it out. Also we want to leverage ACR caching capabilities to PULL images from public registries as a single source to pull images.